# Downloading file to Downloads folder isn't saving

Tags: android

I have a class that downloads a file with the intention of storing it in the user's `Downloads` folder. I have the correct permissions declared. I can see that the file is downloading based on the broadcasts that this class is sending back to the calling activity. However, when this is done, the file does not appear to have been saved anywhere, certainly not in the `Downloads` folder.

Can anyone see why I am not getting access to this folder and/or why it isn't saving correctly? Thank you.

```
public class FileDownloader extends IntentService {

    public static final String FILENAME = "filename";
    public static final String FULLPATH = "fullpath";
    public static final String FILESIZE = "filesize";
    public static final String RECEIVER = "receiver";

    public static String broadcastReceiver;

    public FileDownloader() {
        super("DownloadFile");
    }

    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        String urlPath = intent.getStringExtra(FULLPATH);
        String filename = intent.getStringExtra(FILENAME);
        int filesize = intent.getIntExtra(FILESIZE, 1);
        broadcastReceiver = intent.getStringExtra(RECEIVER);

        // THIS IS WHERE I AM ATTEMPTING TO CREATE A PATH TO THE DOWNLOADS FOLDER
        File outputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), filename);

        if (outputFile.exists()) {
            outputFile.delete();
        }

        downloadFile(urlPath, outputFile, filesize);
    }

    private void downloadFile(String urlPath, File outputFile, int filesize) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(broadcastReceiver);
        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL(urlPath);
            InputStream is = url.openStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

            byte[] b = new byte[2048];
            int length;
            int bytes_downloaded = 0;

            while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
                os.write(b, 0, length);
                bytes_downloaded += length;

                final int progress = (int) ((bytes_downloaded * 100l) / filesize);
                String message = Integer.toString(progress) + "%";
                intent.putExtra("message", message);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(TexasApp.getContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
            }

            intent.putExtra("message", "done");
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(TexasApp.getContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);

            is.close();
            os.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And just in case, this is in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

One final thing: I know that I am navigating the Android 6 permissions correctly, so please assume that this is not related to this issue.

Thank you!

Comment: "the file does not appear to have been saved anywhere, certainly not in the Downloads folder" -- how exactly are you determining this?

Comment: I'm looking at my file manager in both the downloads folder and in the path: "device storage\Android\data\com.mydomain.myapp". Using other downloading methods, this is where I have had files stored previously. I can't guarantee that it isn't dropping somewhere else, but I would be surprised if it were.

Comment: Also, there is no notification posted of a downloaded file and nothing in the download history.

Comment: "there is no notification posted of a downloaded file" -- there is nothing in your code in your question related to a `Notification`. There won't be anything in the download history, as you are not using `DownloadManager`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your file to show up in file manager (e.g., on your development machine), you need to arrange for it to be indexed by the `MediaStore`. This will happen eventually, but it may be several hours. To get it indexed more quickly, use `MediaScannerConnection` and its `scanFile()` method.